# Diferença entre horas superior a 24 horas excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, datetime

Como calcular diferença entre horas no Excel quando essa ultrapassa 24h?

Exemplo:

```
A1 = 05/01/2016 11:40:53
B2 = 06/01/2016 12:29:53

B2-A1 = 24h:49min
```

Porém, ele retorna `00:49`

Comment: Como estás a fazer o cálculo? com código ou usando a ferramenta do excel para adicionar/subtrair? Não estou a ver a parte de programação no problema que apresentas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

É um problema na formatação da célula que está armazenando o resultado.

Se você deixar a formatação como "número" a célula vai exibir `1,03403` (dependendo da quantidade de casas decimais que você pediu para exibir). Se deixar a formatação como "data e hora" um possível resultado será `1/1/00 0:49`, já dentro das opções da formatação do tipo "hora" você pode considerar apenas a diferença no horário ou levar em conta também a diferença de dias.

Você está escolhendo essa opção:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Escolha essa:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>